# MySQL 8: Unpack arbitrary JSON key-value pairings using JSON_TABLE

Tags: mysql, json

I have a json payload that contains arbitrary key -> value pairings that I want to extract and insert into a table.

I don't know the key names in advanced, so they need to be extracted from the JSON dynamically with a MySQL query.

Any help would be appreciated but please:-

- Don't suggest redesigning the schema by refactoring the attribute into object's with consistent keys

  - E.G. `{"myatt1": "value1"}` into `[{ name: "myatt1", "value": "value1 }]`
- Don't suggest doing this in presentation later; javascript, python, java etc.

  - I want to know how to do this with MySQL 8's JSON functions.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `objects`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `objects` (
  `id` SERIAL,
  `payload` JSON NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `objects`
  (`payload`)
VALUES
  (
    '[
      {
          "name": "object #1",
          "attributes": {
              "myatt1": "value1",
              "myatt2": "value2"
          }
      },{
          "name": "object #2",
          "attributes": {
              "another thing": "another value",
              "random tag": "random value"
          }
      }
    ]'
  );
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT `j`.*
FROM
  `objects`,
  JSON_TABLE(
    `payload`,
    '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS(
      `objectid` FOR ORDINALITY,
      `objectname` VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.name',
      NESTED PATH '$."attributes".*' COLUMNS (
        `attribute_id` FOR ORDINALITY,
        `attribute_name` VARCHAR(50) PATH '$', /* Dont know how to do this */           
        `attribute_value` VARCHAR(50) PATH '$'
      )
    )
  ) `j`;
```

**What I've got so far (the 4th column is wrong)**

```
| objectid | objectname | attribute_id | attribute_name | attribute_value |
| -------- | ---------- | ------------ | -------------- | --------------- |
| 1        | object #1  | 1            | value1         | value1          |
| 1        | object #1  | 2            | value2         | value2          |
| 2        | object #2  | 1            | random value   | random value    |
| 2        | object #2  | 2            | another value  | another value   |
```

**Required Results**

```
| objectid | objectname | attribute_id | attribute_name | attribute_value |
| -------- | ---------- | ------------ | -------------- | --------------- |
| 1        | object #1  | 1            | myatt1         | value1          |
| 1        | object #1  | 2            | myatt2         | value2          |
| 2        | object #2  | 1            | random value   | random value    |
| 2        | object #2  | 2            | another thing  | another value   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i26LD93ACdijojnP49RwoC/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [JSON_KEYS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-keys) and [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract):

```sql
SELECT
  `der`.`objectid`,
  `der`.`objectname`,
  `der`.`attribute_id`,
  `der`.`attribute_name`,
  `der`.`attribute_value`
FROM (
  SELECT
    `j`.`objectid`,
    `j`.`objectname`,
    `j`.`attribute_id`,
    `j`.`attribute_value`,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
      JSON_EXTRACT(
        JSON_KEYS(
          `payload`,
          CONCAT(
            '$[', `j`.`objectid` - 1, '].attributes'
          )
        ),
        CONCAT(
          '$[', `j`.`attribute_id` - 1, ']'
        )
      )
    ) `attribute_name`
    FROM
      `objects`,
      JSON_TABLE(
        `payload`,
        '$[*]' 
        COLUMNS (
          `objectid` FOR ORDINALITY,
          `objectname` VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.name',
          NESTED PATH '$.attributes.*' COLUMNS (
            `attribute_id` FOR ORDINALITY,
            `attribute_value` VARCHAR(50) PATH '$'
          )
        )
      ) `j`
) `der`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o8BV7XPEv8uP5BN8higCBN/0).

Comment: Thanks a lot @wchiquito, I've been banging my head against this wall all day. You mentioned that this is one option, can you think of other approaches?